# No viable conversion from 'shared_ptr<Pin>' to 'shared_ptr<Component>s'

Tags: c++11, inheritance, shared-ptr

I have an assignment of creating a Circuit Sim and I'm having issues with NotGate class when I try to use it.

Components is an abstract class.

```
class Component
{
public:
    virtual bool getOutput() = 0;
    virtual void prettyPrint(string padding) = 0;
    virtual void linearPrint() = 0;
};
```

Then I have Pin and NotGate, they inherit through dependency of Components.

```
class Pin {
private:
    bool value;
    string label;

public:
    Pin::Pin(string theLabel) {
    label = theLabel;
}
bool Pin::getOutput() {
    return value;
}

void Pin::setValue(bool newVal) {
    this->value = newVal;
}
};



class NotGate {
private:
    shared_ptr<Component> input;
public:
     NotGate::NotGate() {
    input = make_shared<Component>();
}

bool NotGate::getOutput() {
    if (input == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

void NotGate::setInput(shared_ptr<Component> in) {
    this->input = in;
}
};
```

I created a Pin "c" and a notGate "n1", I want to have "c" as the input for "n1". When I try to do it with the command:

```
n1->setInput(c);
```

It tells me that: `No viable conversion from 'shared_ptr<Pin>' to 'shared_ptr<Component>s'`

I tried creating a new shated_ptr of Components and a bunch of different things that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The error message from the compiler is clear. If you want to be able to use a `shared_ptr<Pin>` when a `shared_ptr<Component>` is expected, you should make `Pin` a sub-class of `Component`. From an abstraction standpoint, it makes sense to me that `Pin` be a sub-class of `Component`.

```
class Pin : public Component
{
   ...
};
```

Comment: Make Pin a sub-class of Component even if the relation is dependency relation?

Comment: @ZexianLi The argument of _setInput_ must be convertible to a `shared_ptr<Component>` and you give a _Pin_ so one way is to have _Pin_ inheriting _Component_, else you have to define an explicit conversion